# How to install/enable intl and xsl extensions after installing PHP 7

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, magento2

I installed `php7/apache2.4/mysql5.6` via [this script](https://github.com/lj2007331/lnmp), but it turns out that the extensions `xsl` and `intl` are missing (need them to run Magento2).

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it is for dev purposes only, the easiest way would be use a PPA like `ppa:ondrej/php-7.0` and then `apt-get install php7.0-intl` and `apt-get install php7.0-xsl`. PPAs should **NEVER** be used in production.

Comment: I did "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0" followed by "sudo apt-get update", then "sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl" and "sudo apt-get install php7.0-xsl".

It could download intl but not xsl. But when I do "php -m" I still don't see intl. Did I do something wrong? And yes it's for testing purpose :)

Comment: You need to enable intl in your php.ini file. Instead of php7.0-xsl, try `libapache2-mod-php7.0` since xsl is packaged with it.

Comment: @Maddy so how do one install PHP 7 in production then if not through PPA?

Comment: @SlavaFominII you could download from http://php.net/downloads.php and compile from src.

Comment: you should read this.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo

Answer (score 20):

You can run `sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl` to get it installed.
You dont need `PPA` adding on 16.10 .

Answer (score 15):

1st you need to add ppa repository to server

this can be done by :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

when PPA repo installed, update the local package cache by :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after this you need to run following command to install intl & xsl extensions

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xsl
```

check the php extensions by :

```
php -m
```

if the extension does load on browser , than you need to check your php.ini for  apache2

that can be found by calling `<?php phpinfo();?>` in **info.php** file