# Is it safe to use a PPA in production?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm preparing an Ubuntu server for a new website and installed PHP7 via [this Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04).

When installing some extensions I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300517/356582) that claims "PPAs should **NEVER** be used in production".

Is this true and if so what is the alternative?

Comment: See [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](http://askubuntu.com/q/35629)

Comment: @timclutton Thanks for the link, that contained everything I needed to know. I couldn't mark my question as a duplicate so have linked and credited you in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [timclutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775731/timclutton)'s comment this question has been answered on askubuntu.com: [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo).