# How to enable php intl

Tags: php, apache

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10
PHP Version: 7.1

I already tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-intl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But when I var_dump `extension_loaded('intl')` it returns false. How can I enable this mod?

Comment: Take a look in the `phpinfo()` output. See where it's looking for `.ini` files, then inspect that location to see if the `intl` plugin is being loaded there. This may take a bit of digging on your part.

Answer (score 2):

on the console enter:

```
sudo phpenmod intl
```

and the restart the apache webserver:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

First you check the php.ini file location. For that use a php file and write:

```
phpinfo();
```

Then load this file in browser. You can see which config file php is using.

[image: loaded configuration file path]

In the php.ini find this line:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

and change to

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Restart your apache

sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Did You refer this  method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294852/how-to-install-enable-intl-and-xsl-extensions-after-installing-php-7)